# Restrict a wifi router to access a specific Android & iPhone app

Tags: wifi, itunes, router

What would be the best solution to have a wifi connection give access only to one specific Android & iPhone App.
This would be used in a shop to allow customers to download the app without making it possible to use the wifi connection for other purpose. (another connection would be dedicated to other uses)

The best thing would be that the app would be pre-loaded in the router so that the download would be the fastest possible. Then the router would only have to communicate with iTunes or Google play for their agreement and statistics reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You will always have a certain device booked in your AP (access point). You can't restrict it to a single application (without policies on the device, which you can't affect).

Making it not possible to use the Wifi connection for other purposes is just a matter of what you connect to the AP and how you configure it. That means don't connect it to another network or internet respectively setup a firewall between the networks.